# npx playwright install-deps fails on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, playwright, debian-buster

When I try to run `npx playwright install-deps` I get an error.

```sh
❯ npx playwright install-deps
Installing Ubuntu dependencies...
Switching to root user to install dependencies...
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                
Hit:3 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                        
Hit:4 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                           
Hit:5 https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian all InRelease                          
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                 
Hit:8 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/Debian_Testing  InRelease
Hit:6 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease        
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libfontconfig1' instead of 'libfontconfig'
Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libenchant1c2a
E: Unable to locate package libicu66
E: Package 'libjpeg-turbo8' has no installation candidate
```

I was able to find out the packages it's trying to install by adding the `--dry-run` flag,

```sh
$ npx playwright install-deps --dry-run
sudo -- sh -c "apt-get update&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fonts-liberation libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libdrm2 libegl1 libgbm1 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxrandr2 libxshmfence1 xvfb fonts-noto-color-emoji ttf-unifont libfontconfig libfreetype6 xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-scalable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-tlwg-loma-otf tt
```

Some of these packages are not present in the list above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Upgrade to 1.25

[Version 1.25](https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes#version-125) now [supports Debian 11 Buster.](https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes#-debian-11-bullseye-support)

Answer (score 5):

Playwright only officially supports the Ubuntu linux distribution 20/22 + Debian 11 see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/library#linux

Answer (score 0):

For pnpm folks, you can just use `pnpm exec playwright install`